# Move onClick From onBindViewHilder To Fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I am implementing an onClick on a **nestedRecyclerView**, the onClick is in the child recyclerView and i am implementing it in the onBindViewHolder of the RecyclerView. I however would like to transfer it to a fragment to i can be able to access its viewmodel once the button is clicked.

This is how my recycler view looks like

```
class ProductAdapter(private val context: Context, private val productModel: List<Product>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductView>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductView {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false)
        return ProductView(view, productModel)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productModel.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductView, position: Int) {
        var product = productModel[position]
        holder.product = listOf(product)
        holder.setClick(object : ItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClickListener(view: View, position: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + productModel[position].productName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        })
    }
    class ProductView(itemView: View, var product: List<Product>) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        private val addToCart: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToCart)
        lateinit var listener: ItemClickListener

        fun setClick(listener: ItemClickListener) {
            this.listener = listener
        }

        init {
            addToCart.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            listener.onItemClickListener(v!!, adapterPosition)
        }
    }
    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClickListener(view: View, position: Int)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move your `setClick()` function and make it public in **adapter**

```
class ProductAdapter (private val context: Context, private val productModel:  
List<Product>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductView>() {

private var listener:ItemClickListener?=null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductView {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false)
    return ProductView(view, productModel)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return productModel.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductView, position: Int) {
    val product = productModel[position]
    holder.product = listOf(product)
}

public fun setClick(listener:ItemClickListener){
    this.listener = listener
}
class ProductView(itemView: View, var product: List<Product>) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
     val addToCart: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToCart)
    lateinit var listener: ItemClickListener

    init {
        addToCart.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        listener.onItemClickListener(v!!, adapterPosition)
      }
   }
 interface ItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClickListener(view: View, position: Int)
     }
}
```

in your **parentAdapter** which include your child adapter pass the interface as contractor parameter and in `ViewHolder` class create a instance from child adapter and call this interface

```
 class ParentAdapter (private val listener: ItemClickListener) 
 { 
 ....
 ....
 class ViewHolder(your parameters){
 var adapter = ProductAdapter (yourParameters);
 adapter.setClick(object:ProductAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
             override fun onItemClickListener(view: View, position: Int) {
                listener.onItemClickListener(view,position)
            }
        });
   }
 }
```

then you can pass fragment context to your **parentAdapter** and implement `onItemClickListener` in this fragment

Comment: Hey, the adapter.setClick is throwing a kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Comment: You have to create a object from childAdpter before using it, but the idea is to pass the `clickListner` interface from parentadapter to childAdapter